# Verify LDAP user password with SSHA-512 hash method

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP to store user information. User entry is an inetOrgPerson object. I use Apache Directory Studio to add userPassword with SSHA-512 hash method.

How can I verify input user password with the password stored in LDAP in my Java application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer: http://gurolerdogan.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssha-encryption-with-java.html

```
SSHA ssha = new SSHA("SHA-512");
String sshaStr = ssha.createDigest("randomString", "mypwd");
//{SSHA}5QxZCiM/zcn0/upHX2uw6ICbgE+PLa9sJz/UpfMAMe1isyxuv+NeW4k4GjRDoTQHnB5QjCKCydJJjUQnT3DEEXJhbmRvbVN0cmluZw==
return sshaStr;
```

Replace {SSHA} with {SSHA-512} you will have a SSHA-512 password to store in OpenLDAP. It's useful when you create new user or update user password.

You can improve the source code, for example replace sun.misc.BASE64Encoder with org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.

Comment: hi user7413, im looking at java codes which uses ssha512 to encode password. i came upon your question. to use it, i will do the following? SSHA-512 ssha512 = new SSHA("SSHA-512");

Answer (score 3):

- Consider not providing a pre-encoded password to the directory server - this prevents the server from checking password quality and managing password history. Transmit the password in clear-text using a secure connection. Configure the server to only accept secure connections or to reject operations other than StartTLS on a non-secure connection.
- The LDAP BIND operation is used to change the authorization state of a connection. The LDAP client transmits a BIND request to the server, the server then matches the provided credentials with the credentials store in the user entry and if successful, changes the authorization state of the connection.

Read an [example](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/samplecode/bind/SimpleBindExample.java) using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/).

Answer (score 2):

Just try to bind using that username and password. The LDAP server will do the checking. This is true of all LDAP implementations, not just OpenLDAP.

In JNDI, 'bind' means either constructing an `InitialContext` with the username and password as the credentials in the environment, or issuing `LdapContext.reconnect()` after changing those things in the environment of an existing context.